# Сжатие бинарного массива в 4 раза

Tags: python, массивы, сжатие

Есть бинарный массив α (из 0 и 1) размером `AxA`. 
Хочу получить новый бинарный массив β размером `BxB`. 
`B` в **2** раза *меньше* `A`, следовательно массив `BxB` в **4** раза *меньше*, чем `AxA`.

Правило следующее:

- "Пиксель" `(x;y)` массива β равен единице, если единице равен *хотя бы* один из следующих элементов массива α: `(2x; 2y), (2x+1; 2y), (2x; 2y+1), (2x+1; 2y+1)`

Имею такой код:

```
def compress_4_times (canvas):
    new_size = 16
    field = [[0]*new_size]*new_size

    for y in range(0, new_size):
        for x in range(0, new_size):
            _x, _y = 2*x, 2*y
            count_active = 0

            if is_pixel_active(canvas, _x, _y):
                count_active += 1
            if is_pixel_active(canvas, _x+1, _y):
                count_active += 1
            if is_pixel_active(canvas, _x, _y+1):
                count_active += 1
            if is_pixel_active(canvas, _x+1, _y+1):
                count_active += 1

            if count_active > 0:
                field[x][y] = True
            else:
                field[x][y] = False

    return field
```

На вход подается массив α, возвращаться должен β.
В данном примере размер α - 32.

**Проблема:**
По ходу выполнения цикла все работает нормально, я проверял принтами: некоторые пиксели становятся True, и судя по всему даже правильные.
Но функция возвращает массив с одними False! В ней нет ни одного True!

Такое ощущение, что после завершения цикла, field почему-то сбрасывается. Почему такое может быть?

Надеюсь, я правильно вывел правило перевода. Например, я хочу превратить такое:

```
 0 0 0 1
 0 1 1 0
 0 0 0 1
 0 0 1 1
```

в такое:

```
 1 1
 0 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта проблема уже много раз обсуждалась тут, нужно только уметь её распознать. Замените инициализацию списка списков на такую:

```
field = [[0] * new_size for _ in range(new_size)]
```

Проблема вашей инициализации в том, что второе умножение там не создаёт новые списки, а клонирует ссылку на один и тот же список много раз. Из-за этого любые изменения в одном из списков тут же отражаются во всех остальных списках - ведь это один и тот же список.

А вот с первым умножением проблем нет, потому что `0` - это скаляр и при его "размножении" создаётся нормальный список из значений, а не из ссылок.

Проверки ваши, кстати, можно сильно сократить (и ускорить - проверки будут выполняться не все, а до первой успешной):

```
            field[x][y] = any((
                is_pixel_active(canvas, _x, _y),
                is_pixel_active(canvas, _x+1, _y),
                is_pixel_active(canvas, _x, _y+1),
                is_pixel_active(canvas, _x+1, _y+1)
            ))
```

А вообще операция, которую вы делаете, называется `pooling`, есть такой штатный слой в нейросетях, в частности в библиотеке `Keras`.

Comment: Спасибо. Понял. Насчет сокращения... Я обычно пишу на C#. Пишу не python, потому что изучаю как раз нейронки, а тут есть keras, но я не очень опытный питонист.

Comment: @МаксимФисман Я чуть поменял код, можно чуть проще это сделать, я там перестраховался сначала. Предыдущие ответы на эту тему надо искать, я так навскидку не помню, но что-то там про списки должно быть и некорректную работу с ними.

Comment: @МаксимФисман Мой основной язык тоже `C#`, я начал изучать `Python` года три назад и мне очень понравилось это дело.

Answer (score 1):

можно еще попробовать такой способ сжатия:

```
matr = [[0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [1,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,1,1,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0]
       ]
matr2=[]

for i in range(0,len(matr),2):
    m = [x or y for x,y in zip(*matr[i:i+2])]
    matr2.append([x or y for x,y in zip(m[::2],m[1::2])])
print(matr2)
```

результат:

```
[[1, 1, 1], 
 [0, 1, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1]]
```

**UPD**

для других степеней сжатия придется этот код частично переписать. Например для сжатия в 9 раз получится так:

```
matr = [[0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [1,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,1,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,1],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0]
       ]
matr2=[]

for i in range(0,len(matr),3):
    m = [x or y or z for x,y,z in zip(*matr[i:i+3])]
    matr2.append([x or y or z for x,y,z in zip(m[::3],m[1::3],m[2::3])])
print(matr2)
```

результат:

```
[[1, 1], 
 [0, 1]]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Как я писал, я не питонист, но я посмотрел описание функции zip.Если я захочу сжимать массив не в 4, а в X^2 раз, то программа продолжит работать при замене `2` на `X`?

Comment: @МаксимФисман,  если надо изменить сжатие, то придется изменить код. Добавил в свой ответ пример для сжатия в 9 раз.